# Are there any good references to learning quaternions?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, quaternions

I'm looking for references (preferably videos) on learning quaternions I understand a lot about them conceptually but when it comes to the actual function I get a little lost can anyone help?

edit#1: I self learn math but I don't know what I don't know therefore act as if you were trying to teach it to a 5 year old I think that's a fair equivalent.

Comment: It might help if you described a bit about your mathematical background (e.g., have you taken abstract algebra, is this for fun or for a class?).

Comment: @IsAdisplayName I self learn math but I don’t know what I don’t know therefore act as if you were trying to teach it to a 5 year old I think that’s a fair equivalent.

Comment: add this to your original post with the "edit" button. The better description you can give, the more likely people will give a good answer!

Comment: @IsAdisplayName will do thanks!

Comment: William Rowan Hamilton invented quaternions almost 200 years ago to study [rotations in three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). This wikipedia article is highly recommended, or any of the references therein you find readable. Feel free to come back with more detailed non-soft questions.

Comment: On references - Conway and Smith "On Quaternions and Octonions" is probably more advanced than you want. John Baez has some useful blogs in the subject which I can't find at the moment, but did a review of the Conway/Smith book here (https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/conway_smith/). If you skim read the review and don't get intimidated by the level of it, you might get a sense where your study may take you. There are profound links with other exceptional mathematical structures and models of potential use physics.

Comment: I wouldn't try teaching quaternions to a 5-year old, so I think it would be helpful if you could actually describe your background (e.g., what are some books you've read before) and what particular things you want to learn about quaternions (how to describe, add and multiply?  history? relation to rotations?)

Comment: @Kimball like I said I self learn so from what I understand quaternions are made up of one real part and 2 imaginary parts i and j which gives you k so if I remember correctly it’s something like a+bi+cj+dk is the formula for rotations though I don’t understand how they rotate

Comment: You might be interested in the YouTube video [Fantastic Quaternions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BR8tK-LuB0&t=5s).